# Why does my Curve freak out when I use Solidify?

Tags: bezier-curves, solidify-modifier

I have an attached project file if anyone is so inclined to take a look.  Basically I have a simple curve object (imported SVG from Illustrator) that I need to solidify, but when I do I get these random spikes coming off the bottom.  Why is this happening and what can I do to fix it?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[Project File (version 3.1)](https://www.dropbox.com/s/gbc2tyyl1heihi2/Curve%20Why.blend?dl=0)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your face was flip when applied Solidify
[image]
*Face Orientation show inner face as red*

Select two points that have problem and <kbd>Right Click</kbd> > Set Handle Type > Vector
[image]
*After set Handle Type*

Comment: Thank you so much man!